# На чём лучше всего делать свой интерактивный web видео-плеер с возможностью выбора сценария продолжения?

Tags: javascript, видео, html5-canvas, online-video

Ребята! Хочу сделать интерактивный web видео-плеер, в котором пользователь сможет выбирать сценарий. То есть, чтобы на определённом моменте ролика прямо поверх видео вылезали кнопки с вариантами продолжения. 
Например, стоит человек на крыше, и в этот момент появляется плашка как в передаче "кто хочет стать миллионером?" - основной вопрос и несколько вариантов: пусть прыгнет вниз или пусть не прыгает. Соответственно, под кнопками у нас ссылки на видео на две разных вариации продолжения.

Ещё надо сделать так, чтобы в полноэкранном режиме все тоже работало, в том числе и на мобильной версии. И вот вопрос: можно ли в html+css+JavaScript реализовать подобный фокус? (Если да, то какие есть кодовые идеи с реализацией?)

Подскажите, куда прицелиться? В какую документацию? Фреймворк? Буду очень благодарна:)

Answer (score 0):

Посмотрите [документацию](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/video) для `<video>`. Всё это можно сделать с помощью чистого HTML и Javascript, вдобавок можете использовать JQuery.

Идея в том, чтобы в определённый момент поставить видео на паузу и поместить некий текст поверх видео. К тексту привязать событие, которое при нажатии на текст заменит параметр `src` и перезапустит видео.

Чтобы пользователь был привязан к сценарию, отключите стандартную панель контроля плеера (пауза, перемотка и т.д.) - для этого не указывайте параметр `controls`.

Вот [здесь](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/Audio_and_video_delivery/cross_browser_video_player) есть пример создания такого видео-плеера со своей системой контроля.